# Geodesic loops in Riemann homogeneous spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let M be a Riemannian homogeneous space, i.e. the isometry group acts transitively. Prove: any geodesic loop (with possible angle at the starting point) is a closed geodesic (smooth at the starting point).

And there is a hint: prove and use the fact that the vector field associated to a one parameter group of isometries is a Jacobi field when restricted to any geodesic.

I just don't know how this hint comes into play..

Comment: It turns out to be not hard..just apply the first variation formula..

Comment: Could you post your own answer? That will be helping others. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my own answer:

Say $\gamma(s),s\in[0,a]$ is a geodesic loop starting at $\gamma(0)=p$. Consider any one parameter group of isometries $g_t$, since the isometry group acts transitively, $g_t p$ takes p to any direction in $T_p M$ as $g_t$ varies. Now note that $g_t \gamma$ is a geodesic variation which preserves length, apply the first variation formula for energy:

$$0=E'(0)=-\int_0^a<U(s),\gamma''(s)>ds+ <U,\gamma'>|_0^a=<U(0),\gamma'(a)-\gamma'(0)>.$$

where $U(s)=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}g_t\gamma(s)$ is the variation vector field. $E'(0)=0$ because it preserves length, and $\gamma''(s)=0$ because it is geodesic. Now recall that $U(0)$ can be any vector in $T_pM$, which forces $\gamma'(a)=\gamma'(0)$. That's geometrically what we need to prove.

Comment: Just to complete the things said about $U(0)$: Let $w \in T_pM$ be arbitrary. Then let $g_t$ be an isometry with $g_t(p) = \gamma_w(t)$, where $\gamma_w$ ist the unique geodesic with $\gamma_w(0) = p$, $\gamma_w'(0) = w$. Then we have $U(0) = \frac{d}{dt}_{\vert t=0} g_t(p) = \frac{d}{dt}_{\vert t=0} \gamma_w(t) = w$.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure whether all of this works, since the variation $g_t\gamma$ may not even be differentiable. Myers-Steenrod (1939) could be useful to conclude that it is, but I'm not sure if even that is enough.